# Getting started with Gulp recieving this TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, gulp

This seems to be happening in the imagemin-svgo node module. When commenting out the try statement then the problem goes away. I can't seem to figure out why I am receiving an error from this code. I have been searching for an answer, everything seems to be up to date. I found the module on GitHub and an then placed that in place of what was there and it didn't seem to solve anything I still get the same error. Below are the errors that I received and the code that I believe is the cause. Please help, any insights are welcome. Thank you in advance.

/theme_name/node_modules/imagemin-svgo/index.js

#### Errors Recieved:

```
events.js:141

  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.exports.fn (/Users/lalice/Desktop/Development/Drupal_sites/Drupal_seven/uncsog/docroot/sites/www.sog.unc.edu/themes/sog/node_modules/svgo/plugins/minifyStyles.js:47:24)
at /Users/lalice/Desktop/Development/Drupal_sites/Drupal_seven/uncsog/docroot/sites/www.sog.unc.edu/themes/sog/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:59:45
at Array.filter (native)
at monkeys (/Users/lalice/Desktop/Development/Drupal_sites/Drupal_seven/uncsog/docroot/sites/www.sog.unc.edu/themes/sog/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:46:39)
at /Users/lalice/Desktop/Development/Drupal_sites/Drupal_seven/uncsog/docroot/sites/www.sog.unc.edu/themes/sog/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:66:17
at Array.filter (native)
at monkeys (/Users/lalice/Desktop/Development/Drupal_sites/Drupal_seven/uncsog/docroot/sites/www.sog.unc.edu/themes/sog/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:46:39)
at perItem (/Users/lalice/Desktop/Development/Drupal_sites/Drupal_seven/uncsog/docroot/sites/www.sog.unc.edu/themes/sog/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:77:12)
at /Users/lalice/Desktop/Development/Drupal_sites/Drupal_seven/uncsog/docroot/sites/www.sog.unc.edu/themes/sog/node_modules/svgo/lib/svgo/plugins.js:18:24
at Array.forEach (native)
```

#### Code from index.js file:

```
    try {
        var svgo = new SVGO(opts);

        svgo.optimize(file.contents.toString('utf8'), function (res) {
            if (!res.data || !res.data.length) {
                return;
            }

            res.data = res.data.replace(/&(?!amp;)/g, '&amp;');
            res.data = new Buffer(res.data);

            if (res.data.length < file.contents.length) {
                file.contents = res.data;
            }
        });
    } catch (err) {
        err.fileName = file.path;
        cb(err);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: How does the code you posted have to do with Gulp specifically? And can you post the console log result of `res` and `res.data` within the `svgo.optimize` callback?

Comment: I am just trying to build gulp so that I can commit to my development site. So there are no console logs. Every time I try to run this command via command line "gulp" I get the above errors. I am new to using Gulp I am just trying to follow the readme file that the last developer wrote. He says to build the site I need to run gulp. But when I do I get the errors that I posted above. I have installed all of the gems that he said were needed, I have also uninstalled the node_modules folder and reinstalled them to see if there was an issue there. I believe that this is being used for images.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(res)` above the first `if` statement to see what's actually being supplied to the function. I'm guessing the function isn't getting what it's expecting.